# Adding more GPU resources to AWS EC2 Ubuntu Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphics-processing-unit

I am running a [g2.2xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/previous-generation/) AWS EC2 instance on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type. The specs on this system are as follows ([source](https://techcrunch.com/2013/11/05/amazon-launches-new-ec2-gpu-instances-for-high-performance-3d-graphics-in-the-cloud/)):

> The g2.2xlarge version comes with 15 GiB memory, 60 GB of local
>   storage, 26 EC2 Compute Units (that’s an Intel Sandy Bridge processor
>   running at 2.6 GHz) and a single NVIDIA Kepler GK104 graphics card
>   (with 1536 CUDA cores).

Is it possible to add more GPU resources to this system on demand--either more CUDA cores or additional graphics cards?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [the elastic GPU option](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/elastic-gpus/details/) isn't available for the G2 class of servers. In fact, none of the GPU instance-types are on the list at all, so this seems to be to add GPU to something that otherwise wouldn't have it. That's the only add-on GPU available I know of, so I suspect the answer here is 'No, not really'.